# Does mongoose ODM allow you to save both sides of an association easily?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

If I have two models, with a `has_many` relationship in Mongoose ODM. ie. User belongs to Team, and Team has many Users:

```
var User = new Schema({
  username    : {type: String, required: true },
  email       : {type: String, required: true},
  team        : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Team'},
  created_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  updated_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});

var exports = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

and

```
var Team = new Schema({
  name        : {type: String, required: true}, 
  users       : [{ type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}], 
  created_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  updated_at  : {type : Date, default : Date.now}
});

var exports = module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', Team);
```

... is there any way to tell Mongoose to add the `user` to the `team.users` collection on `user.save({team: team, ...})`? or do I just have to use the `save()` middleware in the User model?

The reason I ask is that this isn't one of the use-cases covered by the Mongoose docs and this functionality is fairly standard in the rails/mongoid convention.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: you'd have to write that functionality yourself.

However, have you gone through the [schema design doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design)? Specifically linking vs embedding? It's often much easier and more efficient to accomplish the "has_many" relationship through document embedding.

Comment: yea i have. i've found that embedded makes sense when the entities don't exist without the parent. i've also found it much harder to do queries of embedded data explicitly.